# updating a table in sqlite based on matches between anther table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to update a table called stock where the product_id matches the `product_id` of the other table called `stock_in_temp` and also a column called `crm_product_id` has to be `null` or `''`. I am using python sqlite3

I tried this code:

```
conn.execute("UPDATE stock SET stock.quantity += stock_in_temp.quantity FROM stock, stock_in_temp WHERE stock.product_id = stock_in_temp.product_id AND stock_in_temp.CRM_product_id !='' ")
```

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

The updated column at left of the `=` operator must **not** be qualified with the table's name.
Also, `stock` should not be referred again after `FROM` (this is a logical and not syntactical error) and the operator `+=` maybe valid in programming languages but not in SQLite.

Change to:

```
UPDATE stock AS s
SET quantity = s.quantity + t.quantity 
FROM stock_in_temp AS t 
WHERE s.product_id = t.product_id AND t.CRM_product_id <> '';
```

Note that if `quantity` is *nullable* in `stock` then the SET statement must be:

```
SET quantity = COALESCE(s.quantity, 0) + t.quantity
```

I use aliases instead of the table names to shorten the code.